# How to get google account profile photo in android?

Tags: android, gmail, photo, account

I would like to ask whether there's a way to get the profile's photo of google account I'm actually logged on my android device (lvl 10).
I'm able to retrieve my account email from android device, but I can't find a solution to get profile's photo of this email.

Please answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the device´s user information from the [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#UserProfile).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it refers to android 4.0 and I want to the same thing but with android 2.3.x. Do you know any kind of solution for version(s) 2.3.x?

Comment: For what I know, it isn't so easy in previous versions. Prior to 4.x, the user information is not stored as a normal contact that you can obtain through a Content Provider. Although the user configures a Google one or more Google accounts in the device, the profile information of each one is not available locally. You would need to connect via OAuth to a Google API (for instance, the Google+ API: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource), the same way you would do to get the user's Facebook or Twitter profile.